# Add command line arguments with existing one

Tags: python, argparse

Getting an error

> "error: unrecognized arguments: "

For built in arguments when trying to build my own command line arguments. I am defining my arguments as:

```
import argparse

def fn_a(parsed_args):
   print("hello i am in function fn_a")

def fn_b(parsed_args):
   print("hello i am in function fn_b")

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="my first arg scripting")
parser.add_argument('--a', dest='action', action='store_const',const=fn_a)
parser.add_argument('--b', dest='action', action='store_const', const=fn_b)

parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
if parsed_args.action is None:
    parser.parse_args(['-h'])
    parsed_args.action(parsed_args)
```

What may be the problems?

Comment: Last line shouldn't be indented, if it is supposed to run every time.  What commandline are you trying.

Comment: That code isn't valid. The lines `def fn_a` and `def fn_b` shouldn't be indented.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to use a try-except block and only parse known arguments, for example:

```
try:
    parsed_args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args()
except:
    parsed_args = None

if parsed_args and parsed_args.action:
    parsed_args.action(parsed_args)
else:
    try:
        parser.parse_known_args(['-h'])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: `parser.parse_known_args(['-h'])` performs `sys.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the last bit to:

```
if parsed_args.action is None:
    parser.parse_args(['-h'])
parsed_args.action(parsed_args)
```

lets me do:

```
1218:~/mypy$ python stack42067791.py 
usage: stack42067791.py [-h] [--a] [--b]

my first arg scripting

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --a
  --b
1218:~/mypy$ python stack42067791.py --a
hello i am in function fn_a
1218:~/mypy$ python stack42067791.py --b
hello i am in function fn_b
1218:~/mypy$ python stack42067791.py -h
usage: stack42067791.py [-h] [--a] [--b]

my first arg scripting

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --a
  --b
```

That is it responds to `--a` and `--b`, and replicates `-h` if neither is provided.

Anything else produces a standard argparse error message with usage

```
1218:~/mypy$ python stack42067791.py foo
usage: stack42067791.py [-h] [--a] [--b]
stack42067791.py: error: unrecognized arguments: foo
1220:~/mypy$ python stack42067791.py --b foo
usage: stack42067791.py [-h] [--a] [--b]
stack42067791.py: error: unrecognized arguments: foo
```

Using `parse_known_args` lets you throw away the `foo` in that last case.  But why would you want to do that?

```
parsed_args,extras = parser.parse_known_args()
print(parsed_args, extras)
```

prints things like

```
(Namespace(action=None), [])
(Namespace(action=<function fn_b at 0xb71f1b54>), ['foo'])
(Namespace(action=<function fn_a at 0xb744d25c>), [])
```